# Haproxy Server Certificate Common Name

Tags: linux, centos, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I would just like to now if it is possible to define a ACL by the CN of the Backend Server.
So if a Client connects to my proxy, everything is fine and the connection will come to the backend. But there I want to proof if the CN of the Server’s Cert is in a list.
ssl_c_i_dn(CN) - this fetch method is the right thing i need, but unfortunately for the cert of the client…

I hope u can help me!

Comment: Yes, it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478293/haproxy-acl-to-compare-values-in-the-headers ..................

Comment: thanks for your fast reply!

I think I am a bit confused..
In this post he also checks the clients CN or? Otherwise I am asking myself what CN should a Client have?

Comment: Sorry, I was reading too quickly, I missed you wanted to validate >backend< cert (no reputation to comment)

Comment: You're trying to authenticate the back-end server, correct?  That is the `verify required` option, and you need the server's cert (not the key) or an appropriate upstream cert in a `ca-file`.  Checking the CN isn't sufficient.  Please confirm what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: finally i just want to proof where the clients wants to connect via https. My further aim is to create a whitelist or blacklist of domains (including wildcards).